# When the stack pops a value, where is it stored?

Tags: c, memory, stack

Let's take an example : the factorial function.

Your program calls fact(2) which returns 2*fact(1), pushes the call on the stack, then it calls fact(1) which returns 1*fact(0) and eventually calls fact(0) which returns 1.

But then you need to pop all your calls from the stack, if you want to get the result of fact(2). So, to call fact(1) you need to know What returned fact(0) but if you popped it from the stack, where can you find the value ??

I don't know why I said "you", but here "you" is the computer.

What I know of the way the memory is used in C is that it is divided in two parts (dynamic and static). In the dynamic part, there is the heap (where malloc allocates some space) and the stack (whose beginning is indicated by the register SP (Stack Pointer)). My question is about the way the computer manages that stack. There is also the static memory where we can find two main sections : read and write (.bss (initialized to 0) and .data) and read-only (.rodata and .text where the program is stored).

Comment: It seems you are learning the subject and it is new for you. You took explanations you received from someone (or read somewhere) and you understood partially and want to complete your understanding here. It is better if you'll ask for the clarifications from the original place you got your information or post a link here so we'll understand better what you already know and can continue from there.

Comment: would it help you if you imagined the code for `fact(i)` instead of being `return i * fact(i-1);` to be `int x = fact(i-1); return i*x;` ? As in this case, and in a very simplified way, before, for example, fact(1) is popped from the stack, the OS (with the help of your compiler) knows how to pass the return value of fact(1) to  variable `x` of fact(2). And so on...

Comment: Yes it helps, thank you ! However, I do not fully get how the compiler does that. Is the local variable x stored in .data (in the static memory) ?

Comment: You need a book/site on computer architecture, calling conventions etc.   That is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I feel it's not really off-topic, but definitely too broad.

Comment: It's not specified by the C standard. It differs from system to system. In general search for ABI for your specific system. Maybe this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @Alberto: Function return values are often passed in a processor register. They may also be passed in a place provided by the calling routine. The exact mechanisms depend on the hardware architecture and the Application Binary Interface, which is a specification of how routine calls and returns work. If a processor register is used, then, when a function is ready to return, it will load the register with the return value and then remove its data from the stack and jump to the return address.